# What happens if there is a reactive power imbalance in a large grid?

Tags: voltage, power, frequency, power-grid, reactive-power

Consider the Continental Europe power grid.
Supposing there is a 1 GW of active power imbalance in the grid. This would lead to a frequency drop/rise in the whole grid at steady-state.
What happens instead if there is a 1 GVar of reactive power imbalance in the grid?

Comment: This sounds like a hypothetical homework question. What do you think the answer is and why?

Comment: You have enough reputation so you know how this works.  If it looks like homework, we will help, but you have to show some effort.  Clock is ticking!

Comment: Yes of course, I can tell you my idea on this. I suppose that every reactive power imbalance impacts only locally for voltages but not on frequency globally